# Using Django markup in CSS

Tags: python, django, css

So let us say I have loads of stylesheets on a Django site. CSS and JS files are under `static/` in either an app's directory or the global site directory (if it's a common file). I have different color themes going along with different pages, only changing some color values across stylesheets.

Instead of having one whole different stylesheet file for each color theme, and also saving me time should I want to change one single color in the theme that repeats multiple times across the file, I would like to use variables (and for all I know CSS3 variables are both yet unsupported and looked down upon by programmers *and* designers).

Obviously, being on the static directory, I can't send context variables to these files (they aren't called by a Python view request), so here lies the problem: how can I massively change repeated color values in CSS using Django?

Comment: Is the filesystem read-write or read-only?

Comment: (some systems, esp. google app engine, don't let you read /static, and don't let you write anywhere.)

Comment: It's being tested locally. I just want a solution for my problem - I can't send context variables to a file in `/static`, but I wanted to somehow have a reference variable so I can massively set and change CSS color values just like you would change a variable value in a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [CSS property of cascading](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) to your advantage! Don't store colours in your stylesheet, you can specify them in your `<head>` style. For example:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xxx"/>
<style>
body
{
    background-color: {{ colour }};
}
</style>
</head>
```

The colour variable can be set as global in your views. Or better yet, define a class, list or a dictionary with various colours you want to use. Many options here. I think I'd go for

```
Colours={'Grey': ['#999', '#ccc', '#ddd'], 'Blue': ['#00f', '#77f', '#aaf']}
```

Now if you want a subpage to be blue you send `Colours['Blue']` (as `Colour` in my example below) in you context and use one item for the background colour, one for text and one for miscellaneous:

```
<style>
body
{
    background-color: {{ Colour.0 }};
    color: {{ Colour.1 }};
}
div.misc
{
    background-color: {{ Colour.2 }};
}
</style>
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Makes the code slightly less portable, so if someone else runs into this answer, my suggestion is that you make a three-level template-extend: a base template, a template that extends the earlier (with the CSS), a third that adds different widgets if you need, and the final, page-level extension.